# Insert Value After Execute Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables with this structure:

```
ID | Revision   | Purpose
-------------------------
1  |     A      |   3
```

Table 1 is where I save the information, table 2 is filled with a trigger after update table 1. Here is the trigger:

```
TRIGGER `update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table 1` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table 2 (
Id,
Revision,
Purpose,
)
VALUES
(
OLD.Id,
OLD.Revision,
OLD.Purpose,
);
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Everything its fine, but now I want to change the structure of table 2 to this:

```
ID | Revision   | Purpose |  Change
-----------------------------------
1  |     A      |   1     |  Purpose change to 1
```

I want that the user can write a description of what changes from table 1 and then save it to table 2.

I try creating the field and then do the update as always:

```
Update Table 1 ...... where Id = Id
```

And this works but Table 2 can have a lot of rows with the same Id, so this is not an option. Any solution?

Also I try creation the field in table 1 too, but this meant that I have to change all my code but I only want this field in table 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL variable:

1: Before to update the `table 1`, set a user variable `@purpose_change`:

```
 set @purpose_change = 'Purpose change to 1';
```

2: Also, change you trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table 1` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table 2 (
Id,
Revision,
Purpose,
Change
)
VALUES
(
OLD.Id,
OLD.Revision,
OLD.Purpose,
@purpose_change  /* user variable */
);
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The `@purpose_change` will exists in the same connection.