# How to send a MySQL parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, ajax

Hello I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table 1` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table 2 (
Id,
Revision,
Purpose,
Change
)
VALUES
(
OLD.Id,
OLD.Revision,
OLD.Purpose,
@purpose_change  /* user variable */
);
```

$$
DELIMITER ;

I am using C# WebService, Ajax, and JavaScript. Here is my C# methods for update (at the moment doesnt work)

```
"UPDATE table 1 SET Revision=@revision, Purpose=@purpose, @purpose_change=@change WHERE (Id =@id)";
```

Here starts the problem, because I dont know exactly how to send @purpose_channge.

Here is my Web Method.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ActualizarAlerta(int id, string revision, string purpose, string change, int op)
{
    string respuesta = "An Error Has Ocurred.";
    try
    {
        UpdateAlert ua = new UpdateAlert(id, revision, purpose, change);

        int resp = conn.UpdateAlerta(ua, op);

        if (resp > 0)
            respuesta = "Works!.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        respuesta = "An Error Has Ocurred: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

And here is my JavaScript with AJAX call.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",            
    url: urlServer + "ws_alerts.asmx/ActualizarAlerta",                      
    data: '{' +
        '"id":' + id +
        ',"revision":"' + rev +
        '","purpose":"' + pur +           
        '","change":"' + change +
        '","op":' + op + '}',      
    dataType: "json",              
    contentType: "application/json",        
    timeout: 60000,       
    error: function (xhr) {  
        bootbox.alert("Ocurrio un error al procesar la peticion.");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        bootbox.alert(data.d);
    }
});
```

id, rev, change, etc. Are $('#MyId').val()

I know that all the problem is in the Update query but I dont know how to do it correctly, how can I do that?

Comment: This `@purpose_change=@change` in your update statement is wrong, `UPDATE` requires a column to be set to a value.

Comment: shouldn't it be change = @purpose_change

Comment: I know that, but table 1 doesnt have a Change field, Change only exists in table 2.

Answer (score 0):

That is a mysql user variable, you must run a raw query before `UpdateAlerta()`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("set @purpose_change = 'Purpose change to 1';", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

ps (I remember another related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613974/insert-value-after-execute-trigger/) )

Comment: That related question its mine, problem here is that I cant send an specific value for @purpose_change, I have to send this value with another parameter.